# Asking a question with "da" and "datta"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, questions

We use "desu" and "deshita" to make the polite form and "ka" to make it a question, for example:

```
Tokyo ga suki desu ka? (Do you like Tokyo?)
Tokyo ga suki deshita ka? (Did you like Tokyo?)
```

How can I ask **the same questions** using the dictionary, casual forms of "desu" and "deshita" which are "da" and "datta"?

Should I add "ka" at the end of a sentence? Or just replace "desu" and "deshita" with "da" and "datta"?

P.S. I don't need a long explanation, but rather a simple answer. The information I've found so far is ambiguous.

**P.S.2**

How common and ok to use this in informal speech (without **ka**)?:

```
Tokyo ga suki da/datta?
```

Just yes or no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of *desu, deshita*, and *datta* appear normally before *ka*.

But *da* is an exception.  In main clauses (like your examples), *da* is deleted before *ka*:

```
 desu    + ka   →　　 desu ka
 deshita + ka   →　deshita ka
 da      + ka   →　　      ka
 datta   + ka   →　　datta ka
```

In subordinate clauses (like *[dare da ka] shiranai*), *da* sometimes appears before *ka*.

---

Although you want a short answer, you should also consider alternate ways of forming questions, for example using rising intonation, omitting *ka*.  In informal speech, people don't always use the textbook-style question with *ka* at the end.

Comment: ... As well as in case of "datta". For example, **Tokyo ga suki da/datta?** Is that acceptable? I don't want to dig into the details.

Comment: @jawanam `- da?` is not acceptable. `- datta?` is OK because you have the form after you putting `ka?` and removing `ka`.

Comment: **because you have the form after you putting ka?** -- what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @jawanam I mean, if you start with `suki datta.`, you'll get `suki datta ka?`, then `suki datta?`. But with `suki da.`, you'll get `suki ka?`, then `suki?`. So `datta?` actually exists but you can't assume simply that plain ending + `?` would make a question.

Answer (score 4):

I try to be simple, but there's always something that needs explanation.

> *Should I add "ka" at the end of a sentence? Or just replace "desu" and "deshita" with "da" and "datta"?*

Grammatically you ***can*** have them (see @snailboat's answer), but I'm not sure if you ***should***. The reason is that, plain form + `ka` often sounds too harsh, unless you're a manly man talking to your child or lover. Otherwise it simply sounds like a rigid boss, a soldier, or a police officer (during interrogation). To avoid that, you should omit `ka` and say `Tokyo ga suki (datta)?`, where the `?` is accompanied with rising intonation.

---

The main use of plain form + `ka` is to form indirect speech.

> Tokyo ga suki (datta) ka to kikareta.
> *I was asked if I (had) liked Tokyo.*

Comment: **To avoid that, you should remove ka and say Tokyo ga suki (datta)** - and where is "da"? Can't I say **Tokyo ga suki da?**

Comment: @jawanam No. `Tokyo ga suki da.` → add _ka_ for question → `Tokyo ga suki ka?` (_da_ removed) → omit _ka_ → `Tokyo ga suki?`

Comment: and how would I reply to Toky ga suki ka? With "da" --> "suki da"?

Comment: In addition to the harshness mentioned in your answer, plain form + か is -- with the right tone of voice -- a rhetorical question. Rhetorical questions sometimes have a pause before the か → 「そういうこと…か」

Comment: @jawanam Both basically work, with or without. That would be another complicated question if you want to know :)