# It it correct / normal to use か after だ?

Tags: particles, questions, particle-か

I've heard 'ですか' all too often in textbook Japanese.

I've personally never heard だ and か used together - only 'の' or a rising intonation.

Eg:

> なまえはなんですか？ vs なまえはなんだか？

Is it normal/natural in the second case? How do you properly convey a question in this case if not with か?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking a question with "da" and "datta"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27705/asking-a-question-with-da-and-datta)

Answer (score 3):

> なまえはなんですか？ vs なまえはなんだか？
>   Is it normal/natural in the second case? How do you properly convey a question in this case if not with か?

As a simple interrogative sentence "What is [your name]?", 「[なまえ]はなんだか？」 doesn't sound natural/correct. You can instead say:

> [なまえ]は**なに**？ -- friendly, gender-neutral
>   [なまえ]は**なんだ**？ -- relatively masculine, can be blunt
>   [なまえ]は**なにか**？ -- not common in daily conversation, might sound strong/harsh/rigid

Similarly, to say for example 「これは[誰]{だれ}の[傘]{かさ}ですか？」 "Whose umbrella is this?" in the casual form:

> これは誰の傘？
>   これは誰の傘だ？
>   これは誰の傘か？
>   (×これは誰の傘だか？)

---

As to yes-no questions, to say for example 「これは[山田]{やまだ}さんの傘ですか？」 "Is this Yamada-san's umbrella?" in the casual form:

> これは山田さんの傘？ -- commonly used by both genders of all ages
>   これは山田さんの傘か？ -- fairly common but I think it's more used by males, can sound blunt/strong
>   (×これは山田さんの傘だ？ / ×これは山田さんの傘だか？)

Answer (score 2):

Your question very closely mirrors [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27705/asking-a-question-with-da-and-datta), and I highly recommend you look into it.

The simple answer to your question is that saying ～だか is somewhat unnatural, as you suspected.  Like @snailplane mentioned in the comment below, ～だか does happen occasionally if something is being left unsaid. i.e. ～なんだか（わからない）

~のか is the question form of ～のだ、and here we see that the だ is omitted when answering a question.  The same holds true for pretty much every other case, except subordinate clauses as discussed in the [answers](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/27710/22352) [(second answer)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/27714/22352) to the [linked question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27705/asking-a-question-with-da-and-datta).

However, in informal speech, you'll find that often Japanese will omit saying か、with a rising intonation at the end of the sentence that says, "this is a question."  This is something that you'll have to listen to a bit to get the hang of. So, if you're fairly new to the language, I would recommend using か until you get the hang of things.

Read both of the answers to the [linked question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27705/asking-a-question-with-da-and-datta), because they do a very good job of explaining this concept.

Comment: But people do say だか if they're leaving something unsaid, like 何が何だか（分からない）

Comment: Op, You're right.  I'll tweak that.

Comment: @snailplane Couldn't it be said that 何だか（分からない）has a subordinate clause with the main clause left unsaid?

Comment: Yep!  Precisely.  But in that case it may not be unnatural sounding.