# is this そうなんだか a valid sentence?

Tags: questions, copula, particle-か

If そうなんですか (sounandesuka) is formal, how come it's not often that I hear of そうなんだか (sounandaka) as casual version or maybe that I just don't hear enough? thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It it correct / normal to use か after だ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48109/it-it-correct-normal-to-use-%e3%81%8b-after-%e3%81%a0)

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27705/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because speaking casually very often means discarding the question mark か as well, making the casual version of そうなんですか？ -> そうなんだ？
It's just not そうなんだか, but "だか" that you wouldn't hear in any sentence, because you would simply stop at だ。

Comment: It's pretty frequent that そうなんですか・そうなのか aren't really questions at all